# Trying to understand a proof involving connected and continuity concepts

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to understand the proof of the following theorem: If $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is contiuous and let X be a connected space, then f(X) is a connected space.

In the proof, we construct another function $g:X \rightarrow Z$ obtained by restraigning X. Then, we show that if $Z$ is not connected, then X is not connected.

What I don't understand is why do we construct $g$. My guess is that $f(X) = Z$ but I am not sure about that equality.

Comment: How are $Z$ and $g$ defined here?

Comment: Yes: they want to show that $f(X)$ is connected, so they  have to restrict $f$ to its image and they denote $f(X) = Z$.

Comment: It might be better to use the definition of connected: unable to be written as a disjoint union of nonempty clopen subsets.  If $f(X)$ were disconnected, what would that mean for the preimage $f^{-1}(f(X)) = X$?

Comment: @Mnifldz another perfectly okay definition is that $X$ is disconnected iff there exists a continuous onto map $g:X \mapsto \{0,1\}$.  Maybe that's what's happening here.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ Y \subset f(X)$ such that Y is both open and closed. Thus by continuity $ f^{-1}(Y)$ is also open and closed in X. But that means it is whole of the  space .Thus $Y = f(X)$. Hence proved.

Comment: The post doesn't ask for a proof, it asks for an explanation of why a proof goes in a particular direction